# Django directory plugin

Tags: python, django, plugins, web, directory

Is there any Django plugin or reusable app available that we can use to add online directory feature to our Django based website?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting? Something to allow users to browse the directories on the server? A contact directory with names, phone numbers etc? Or do you mean an online store?

Comment: Business listing directory that will have name, description, address, phone number, email etc for each business listed in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You will not find something like that, because using django means you can do that with just a few lines of code by yourself. Django is not a CMS, but a framework, which means you are one level deeper. A lot of the things where you would use a plugin in a CMS are common tasks for django programmers, so there really is no need for a plugin to display such stuff as you mentioned.

Comment: I think its going a little too far to say that you won't find something like that. There are tons of pluggable/reusable apps or "packages" for django (see [here](http://www.django-apps.com/), [here](http://djangopackages.com/), google), but finding a pluggable app that fits your needs and is being maintained is a challenge.

Comment: I think it will take longer to look for such an app, than to write it yourself.